is there any reason why 'the way how' cannot be used?
We usually say


This is the way (that) the story went.
This is how the story went.


But we don't say


This is the way how the story went.


Why is that?

"how the story went" could not work as an attribute modifying "the way."



This is the way (that) the story went.
This is how the story went.
*This is the way how the story went.


How is a free relative pronoun here, similar to those in the following three examples:

(117a) What you say is true
(117b) I will go where you go
(117c) I don't like how he behaved toward her


They are characterised by the fact that the wh-pronoun what/where/how appears to be antecedentless, in that it doesn't refer back to any other constituent in the sentence ... what and how can serve as free relative pronouns, but not as appositive or restrictive pronouns ...

Back to the OP's examples, the relative clause

(1) (that) the story went

has the way as antecedent.

(2) how the story went

is a free relative clause similar to example (117c).  Note there's no antecedent.

(3) *This is the way how the story went.

is invalid as how cannot be a restrictive pronoun, as explained earlier.  The antecedent the way shouldn't be there.
